# What is the suggested volume method to use for zookeeper and broker for Apache kafka?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, persistent-storage

What is the suggested volume method to use for zookeeper & broker for Apache Kafka running in the kubernetes environment?

I'm running a 3 node cluster and tried using [persistent volume](http://refer:%20https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), but is there any recommended volume method by Apache Kafka?

Answer (score 1):

You can use helm charts to install Apache Kafka on Kubernetes (this is the recommended way by Confluent). You can find the charts [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts). Also, you have in that charts some default persistence sizes for Kafka. Also Confluent recommends using Shared Storage rather than Local Storage. You can find more details [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-kubernetes-could-you-should-you) and [here](https://www.confluent.io/wp-content/uploads/Recommendations-for-Deploying-Apache-Kafka-on-Kubernetes.pdf).

The recommended storage is: 4gb for Zookeeper and for Kafka you have: `r4.xlarge` on AWS, `n1-highmem-4` on GCP, `DS5v2` on Azure and **12 core**, **128GB RAM**, **12 disks server on-premises**. You cand find more [here](https://www.confluent.io/wp-content/uploads/apache-kafka-confluent-enterprise-ref-architecture.pdf).